# What is the difference between a hair coat and a fur coat in dogs?

Tags: dogs, grooming, terminology, breeds

Listening to dog breeders talk about dogs, I sometimes hear them mentioning that a breed has a "hair coat" or a "fur coat".

What are the differences between the two types of coat? Do they have different bathing or grooming requirements? How can I tell if my dog has hair or fur?

Comment: I know this was asked before here, but I can't find the question.  At least, I know a question concerning dog hair vs. dog fur was asked.

Comment: [This article](http://www.dogplay.com/Articles/MyArticles/hair_vs_fur.html) suggests that there's no difference, it's just a made-up distinction between longer or shorter hair lengths.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there's a formal distinction between a double and single coat:

> A dog's coat may be a double coat, made up of a soft undercoat and a coarser topcoat, or a single coat, which lacks an undercoat.

However:

> The terms fur and hair are often used interchangeably when describing a dog's coat, however in general, a double coat, e.g., like that of the Newfoundland and most mountain dogs, is referred to as a fur coat, while a single coat, like that of the Poodle, is referred to as a hair coat.

source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_(dog)

Comment: This is a decent answer (3.5 on a 5 scale). I agree that the question has been asked before - somewhere - and answered in greater detail. IIRC, it has to do with undercoats, and which type of follicle is involved, which validates the wikipedia statement.